# Whether editing the Release definition or Build definition to pass variable group or Schedule using REST API is a good method

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am able to pass a Variable group or a Schedule toa release pipeline using REST API using "PUT". But the problem is this will edit the release definition. I would like to know is this a good practice of editing the release definition using REST API to achieve this ??

Answer (score 0):

Asking questions about something being good is often subjective. I would say that it depends what your actual end goal is. If you have *n* release pipelines where *n* is a large number, and updates to *x* number of those release pipelines are all the same, then scripting the edit is a good way to manipulate the release definitions as your organization or team requirements evolve. If you're talking about regular and/or frequent manipulations to the release definitions for some ambiguous or ill-defined part of your process or business culture, then you might want to ask about those requirements and why the exist and force you to change your Build/Release pipeline. Those requirements may need to continue to exist, and in such cases, I would suggest (if possible) designing the pipeline is such a way that other tooling can use the pipeline **as it is** through the REST api to create RELEASES to meet the requirements for alternate variables or scheduling.

Accessing the pipeline through the REST api allows your process to be "flexible", yet insisting on as much consistency as possible over time will be what builds developer and stakeholder trust in the system to NOT be the cause of quality issues.

Comment: What you meant by "other tooling"

Comment: custom software such as scheduled tasks, scripts, etc that can be managed separately from your release definition. These tools would use the REST api to create releases with the appropriate parameters at the appropriate time etc rather than writing tools to change the actual pipeline.